# Is there a way to turn off the passcode screen in iOS 8 when my app prompts user for fingerprint

Tags: ios, ios8, touch-id

It's frustrating when iOS 8 takes over my app's screen when the user fails the TouchID local authentication more than a few times.  I feel like I should have control and I should decide what to do when a user fails and our backend is programmed as such.

So is there any way to turn off the passcode screen from popping up in the middle of my app?

This is the code I use in order to pop the TouchID on the screen:

```
-(void)checkFingerprint
{
    LAContext *myContext = [[LAContext alloc] init];
    NSError *authError = nil;
    NSString *myLocalizedReasonString = @"Please scan your fingerprint to open app";
    NSString *myFallbackTitle = @"";
    [myContext setLocalizedFallbackTitle:myFallbackTitle];

    //does this iPhone do fingerprint, is a at least one registered on the phone?
    if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError])
    {
        //yes it does, and the fingerprint is registered on the phone!
        //now lets check for the fingerprint :)
        [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
                  localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                           ^{[self showLocalAuthenticationResult:success :error];});
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        //Could not evaluate policy; look at authError and present an appropriate message to user
        NSLog(@"checkFingerprint()::local authentication/fingerprint error remember both fingerprint and passcode have to be enrolled on iOS %@", authError);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that if I go to Settings TouchID and I turn off the passcode, iOS tells me that a fingerprint is no longer enrolled either...

Comment: For now, the API is what it is.  You should consider filing a bug report with Apple (bugreport.apple.com) and document your enhancement request there, they are very reasonable when a logical case is made.

Comment: I ran the Apple example code and it just returns an error after 3 incorrect scans and their code is basically the same as yours. I am running on 8.02. The keychain based example exhibits the behaviour you describe